# Issues in firebreath plugin in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, npapi, firebreath

I am trying to create a [firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org/) plugin for linux which i already build in windows and it is working in windows. 
Can I use same code for ubuntu? if yes, how? As I tried but failed. 
Later I tried to create same plugin from start instead of using  windows version code of my plugin but I got following errors. any solution?

```
root@roshan-HCL-Notebook:/home/roshan/fbprojects/PLSplugin# sh firebreath/prepmake.sh  . build 
firebreath/prepmake.sh: 7: firebreath/prepmake.sh: source: not found 
firebreath/prepmake.sh: 9: firebreath/prepmake.sh: pushd: not found 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (Project): 
  project PROJECT called with incorrect number of arguments 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (include_platform): 
  Unknown CMake command "include_platform". 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
firebreath/prepmake.sh: 11: firebreath/prepmake.sh: popd: not found
```

Comment: By the way, there really is no need to do development things as root.

Comment: I just tried to run it with root permission thought it would run. Usually i don't do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `sh` (which doesn't have `source`, `pushd` & `popd`), use `bash` - or rather just run the script directly:

```
firebreath/prepmake.sh . build
```

Comment: Thanks! I already got same answer from google group but valuable answer. I am novice in linux so don't know these basics.

Comment: I don't know why firebreath tutorial says "sh premake.sh" . Can you tell me? @Georg

Comment: Not sure, which tutorial do you mean?

Comment: My mistake.. I mean firebreath Documentation http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Building+on+Linux 
@Georg

Comment: Ah, fixed. Apparently it worked for whatever `sh` was for the author.